# Elasticsearch delete-by-query returns success but records persist?

Tags: json, rest, lucene, elasticsearch

I am attempting to delete records from elasticsearch using the delete by query [API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/delete-by-query/)

Executing:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:4040/search/foo/_query -d '{
  "term": {
    "record id": "0f9eaa6f-90bb-4dee-9ecb-78a5d04719c0"
  }
}'
```

results in:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "_indices": {
    "foo": {
      "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yet, querying:

```
curl -XGET localhost:4040/search/foo/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "record id": "0f9eaa6f-90bb-4dee-9ecb-78a5d04719c0"
    }
  }
}'
```

gives me:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

with the 5 records printed...

I have tried running:

```
curl -XGET localhost:4040/search/foo/_refresh
```

but still results are returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are deleting using the `term` query and you are searching using the `match` query. These are two different queries. The `term` query doesn't analyze the supplied query term while the `match` does. So these two queries may produce different results depending on how your `record id` field is analyzed.

Comment: Thank you. What I needed was: curl -XDELETE localhost:4040/search/foo/bar/_query -d '{"match" : {"record id" : "0f9eaa6f-90bb-4dee-9ecb-78a5d04719c0"}}'